# Removing a file completely from Github Classroom

Tags: github

I have followed this way to remove a file permanently from my GitHub Repo

https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

However I am not sure If this also works with the Github Classroom ?  I have pushed a file accidentally that I do not want anyone to see. Is this a Safeway to make sure the file is deleted 100% and no other contributor has access to it ? Is this going to appear as a new commit ?Assuming that my professor has not cloned it yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the step 6 (`git push origin --force` of your branch you have cleaned up), that should be OK.

But that supposes nobody cloned that branch (as you mention).
And it supposes that a force push was not disabled on the remote side (as it was in [issue 458](https://github.com/education/classroom/issues/458))